# How do I know if I'm doing Async Page correctly

Tags: c#, asp.net, asynchronous

I have a aspx with this directive:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Logs.aspx.cs" Inherits="Logs_Logs" Async="true" %>
```

And the .cs:

```
.....

private readonly Action<string> zipArquivoAction;

public Logs_Logs()
{
    zipArquivoAction = ZipArquivo;
}

protected void LkbGZip_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    LinkButton lkbGZip = (LinkButton) sender;
    AddOnPreRenderCompleteAsync(BeginAsyncOperation, EndAsyncOperation, lkbGZip.CommandArgument);
}

IAsyncResult BeginAsyncOperation(object sender, EventArgs e, AsyncCallback cb, object state)
{
    return zipArquivoAction.BeginInvoke((string)state, cb, state);
}

void EndAsyncOperation(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    zipArquivoAction.EndInvoke(ar);
}

private void ZipArquivo(string arquivoCaminho)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10000);
}
```

If I put a breakpoint in any method and call System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread, always return the same Thread, what means that I am not using IO Thread, right?

```
System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread
{System.Threading.Thread}
    base {System.Runtime.ConstrainedExecution.CriticalFinalizerObject}:             
{System.Threading.Thread}
    ApartmentState: MTA
    CurrentCulture: {pt-BR}
    CurrentUICulture: {pt-BR}
    ExecutionContext: {System.Threading.ExecutionContext}
    IsAlive: true
    IsBackground: true
    IsThreadPoolThread: true
    ManagedThreadId: 5
    Name: null
    Priority: Normal
    ThreadState: Background
```

Answer (score 1):

Turn on tracing and look for calls to Begin AsyncOperation and End AsyncOperation. These should appear after End PreRender.

[image: Async page trace screenshot]

For more see:

[Asynchronous Pages in ASP.NET 2.0](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx)

Comment: My trace dont show any BeginAsyncOperation =/
What I am doing wrong?

Comment: I think that he writed that to Trace manually. Category is empty

Comment: Adding to Fujiy's comment, you can call Trace.Write("BeginAsyncOperation"); and Trace.Write("EndAsyncOperation"); in BeginAsyncOperation() and EndAsyncOperation() respectively and you should see the entries in the trace view as shown in the above screenshot.